# SQL query for to get values from 2 combined table at very fast rate

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 2 tables

```
              Users
--------------------------------------------
Uid   |   Name    |
--------------------------------------------
   1  |   sdfa    | 
   2  |   dsf     |
```

And Second Table as

```
           Log
--------------------------------------------
Uid   |   log    |  size  |  file   | time
--------------------------------------------
   1  |   dea    |   2    |   sadf  | timestamp
   1  |   dea    |   2    |   sadf  | timestamp
   2  |   eff    |   25   |   sadf  | timestamp
```

Per user in log table get updated **3 times per 5 seconds**.

I need an optimized QUERY to get Name, log,size,file, 
time per user in a table. With the latest updated record each user.
i.e. Latest update of user only to be shown not ALL.

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, log, size,file,time FROM log 
WHERE userid IN (SELECT uid FROM users) As b ORDER BY time ASC
```

// PROBLEM here is that for every user order is not the latest 
but Order by here orders the new table
So I tried,

```
SELECT a.userid,a.name, b.log, b.size,b.file,b.time 
FROM users a LEFT JOIN ON  log b WHERE a.userid=b.userid 
ORDER BY b.time ASC
```

But the interviewer told this is also wrong, please advice.

Comment: if you want to order by latest, wouldn't it be then `desc`?

Comment: Oh sorry it was ASC,
But the interviewer asked that at very fast rate this query will not work properly, and asked me for alternate query, Is there any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no distinct `rank` function in MYSQL. But you could utilize a variable in that matter.

Check on [SQLFIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50105/1) for the sample. The time stamp is not formatted, which you may do on your own.

Table users

```
UID     NAME
1   a
2   b
```

Table logs

```
UID     LOG     SIZE    FILE    TIME
1   lg1     2   f1  20140220173550
1   lg2     2   f2  20140220173551
2   lg3     25  f3  20140220173552
```

Check on **execution plan** for each of the answers to find the fastest for your case.

```
SELECT x.uid, u.name, x.log, x.size, x.file,
x.time FROM users u INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT l.uid, l.log, l.size, 
          l.file, l.time,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
   FROM   logs l, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
   ORDER BY  rank DESC
) AS x 
ON u.uid = x.uid
GROUP BY u.uid
ORDER BY x.time DESC
```

Results

```
UID     NAME    LOG     SIZE    FILE    TIME
2   b   lg3     25  f3  20140220173552
1   a   lg2     2   f2  20140220173551
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the latest log entry for each user.  If your tables are properly indexed, it should be fast.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    log a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  uid, MAX(timestamp) max_date
        FROM    log
        GROUP   BY uid
    ) b ON  a.uid = b.uid AND
            a.timestamp = b.max_date
join users u on u.uid = a.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle you would have used rank. But assuming that there is no logs with the same timestamp for the same user we can try:

```
SELECT u.name, l2.log, l2.file, l2.size
  FROM (SELECT l1.uid, max(time) as last_log
          FROM Log l1
      GROUP BY l1.uid ) last_logs
  JOIN Users u ON u.uid   = last_logs.uid
  JOIN Log  l2 ON l2.uid  = last_logs.uid 
              AND l2.time = last_logs.last_log
```

This way we only send the **last** log for each user.

Disclaimer. I have not tested this query in Mysql.